# .Net Core Entity Framework - Discrimator TPH

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-fluent-api

I'm currently trying to write to a table which inherits from an abstract base class. When I try to do this I get the following error (The ContactMethod property is the discriminator):

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name 'ContactMethod'.
```

EmailContactDetails.cs:

```
public class EmailContactDetail : ContactDetail
{
    [ApiMember(Description = "The Contact Method")]
    public override ContactMethod ContactMethod => ContactMethod.Email;

    [ApiMember(Description = "Email Address")]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
}
```

EmailContactDetailConfiguration.cs:

```
public class EmailContactDetailsConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<EmailContactDetail>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<EmailContactDetail> builder) => Configure(builder, "dbo");

    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<EmailContactDetail> builder, string schema)
    {
        builder.Property(x => x.EmailAddress).HasColumnName("EmailAddress").HasColumnType("nvarchar(255)");
    }
}
```

ContactDetail.cs:

```
public abstract class ContactDetail
{
    [ApiMember(Description = "The Identifier")]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [ApiMember(Description = "The Contact Method")]
    public virtual ContactMethod ContactMethod { get; set; }
}
```

ContactDetailConfiguration.cs

```
public class ContactDetailsConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<ContactDetail>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<ContactDetail> builder) => Configure(builder, "dbo");

    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<ContactDetail> builder, string schema)
    {
        builder.ToTable("ContactDetails", schema);

        // Table per hierarchy. all subclasses share the same db table for performance.
        builder.HasDiscriminator(x => x.ContactMethod)
            .HasValue<EmailContactDetail>(ContactMethod.Email);

        builder.Property(x => x.Id).HasColumnName("Id").IsRequired().HasColumnType("uniqueidentifier").ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
    }
}
```

I've tried hiding the discriminator "ContactMethod" by adding the following to the ContactDetailConfiguration.cs file:

```
builder.Ignore(x => x.ContactMethod);
```

Once I've done that I end up with the following error

```
The entity type 'EmailContactDetail' is part of a hierarchy, but does not have a discriminator property configured.
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Sorry just adjusted the question. Looking to see if I've done something wrong to cause the errors or if someone has a work around.

Comment: So you want to "hide" the `ContactMethod` property? Hide from whom? Because currently you are hiding it from EF which definitely needs it.

Comment: Originally I didn't hide it and I got: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name 'ContactMethod'.

Comment: You've shouldn't try hiding it from EF. The initial error indicates that there is no such column in your database table. Make sure the table and model are in sync (i.e. add migration, update database etc.)

Comment: Could you write your comment into an answer. I was getting confused between the old way of doing discriminators and the new way. The old way requiring the column name to be "DISCRIMINATOR" while the ef core requiring the same column name as described with .HasDiscriminator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't hide the property configured as TPH discriminator from EF because it is essential for EF Core implementation of the TPH strategy.

The initial error simply indicates that your model and database are out of sync. It's true that by convention EF Core uses `string` [shadow property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/shadow-properties) and column called `Discriminator`. But the whole purpose of `HasDiscriminator` fluent API is to allow changing the discriminator property/column type, as well as mapping it to an existing property of your entity model.

Which is the case here. You've told EF Core to use your existing property `ContactMethod` as discriminator, hence EF Core is looking for column named `ContactMethod` in the database table. So to resolve the issue, simply update your database from the model (using the usual procedure when model is changed - add new migration, update database etc).